# Clearing the $viewValue on Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a form with fields that are dependent on each other, displayed using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Selecting a team from a bootstrap typeahead then populates a list of players that can then be selected in a second typeahead. When the user changes the team I reload the list of players and clear the currently selected player value.

The player options are loaded correctly based on the team, but the issue is that the typeahead is not showing the options when clicked on - I think I might be running afoul of the $viewValue being in a weird state and not matching any of the existing options. If I type a letter that happens to match one of my unseen choices then I get the matching values, and clearing anything that has been typed restores the full list.

I would like the full list to be available on the first click - I suspect I need to reset the $viewValue properly, and I have toyed with trying `$setViewValue` and `$render()` on the player model, but have not gotten anywhere.

```
<div class="options">
Team: <input type="text" 
          name="team"
          placeholder="Select team"
          ng-model="selectedTeam" 
          uib-typeahead="team as team.name for team in league | filter:$viewValue" 
          typeahead-editable="false"
          typeahead-min-length="0"
          class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="options">
<input type="text" 
        name="player"
        placeholder="Select player"
        ng-model="selectedPlayer" 
        uib-typeahead="player as player.name for player in players | filter:$viewValue" 
        typeahead-editable="false"
        typeahead-min-length="0"
        class="form-control">
</div>
```

The controller that looks for a team change and then resets the player options and selected value:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedTeam.id', function(newTeamID) {

    // clears any currently selected player ng-model
    $scope.selectedPlayer = null;

    if (!newTeamID)
    {
      return;
    }

    // sets up the list of available players
    $scope.pullPlayers(newTeamID);

});
```

Full plunkr is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MoNkZA34MBTkz5ZOkeqk?p=preview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset `players` typeahead value from controller you might want something like this:

```
 $scope.$watch('selectedTeam.id', function(newTeamID) {
    if (!newTeamID)
    {
       $scope.players = [];
       $scope.teamForm.player.$setViewValue('');
       $scope.teamForm.player.$render();
       return;
    }

    // sets up the list of available players
    $scope.pullPlayers(newTeamID);
  });
```

Here is a [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aVj8IaQEUpAfVdaUmwDG?p=preview)

Comment: Definitely is working in my simplified plunkr example. Trying to apply it now to my actual code that is slightly more complex (drives two lists - one of which works, the other one is being wacky). Digging into it now.

Comment: I have 2 dependent lists (say "players" and "coaches"), and when clearing the main option (teams) it also causes one of the typeaheads to open itself up with the previous options (although an ng-repeat shows that the options have been cleared, as you suggested). I can't get it to replicate it in a plunkr - if I do, I'll ask a new question. But this fixed my original issue - apparently it worked better to $setViewValue on clearing the driver list, rather than on setting the new value.